# docker-compose up is not mapping port

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I know this has been asked multiple times already, but I am not able to find any solution to this. I am creating an application with Node.js and is trying to use `postgres` as a database with it. I am using `docker-compose` to start both the web server as well as the postgres server container. Here's how my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like -

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:12'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=my_admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - my_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  my_db:
```

Here's how my dockerfile looks like -

```
FROM node:12.16.2

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Add Tini
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.18.0
RUN wget https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "-e", "143", "--"]

# Setup code
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . /app

# Run on port 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
USER node
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, both the containers start and I can see the output. But when I try to run `curl -i http://localhost:3000` it shows an error, but works if I ssh into the container.

Am I missing something here?

**Update:**

Running `docker ps` shows this -

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0b2a43079005        postgres:12         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   todo_postgres_1
0b0f1afd4fa1        todo_web            "/tini -e 143 -- yar…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   todo_web_1
```

**Update 2:**

Here's how my. `app.ts` file looks like (I am using `hapijs`) -

import Hapi from '@hapi/hapi';

```js
const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
  });

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
      return reply.response('Hello');
    },
  });

  await server.start();
  console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Comment: Add quotes around the ports, i.e: `- "3000:3000"`. What is `docker ps` showing you as mapped ports?

Comment: @Jcl I just updated the `docker ps` output in the question. I tried with the quotes already.

Comment: When your application starts up, does it print something like `listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000/`?  If it says that (and not "0.0.0.0") then it will be unreachable from outside the container, and you need to change the process's bind address.  Editing the question to include the application code that includes that startup call will help diagnose this.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've added the application code. I am binding to `localhost`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just changed it to `0.0.0.0` and it worked. I didn't understand it though. Can you please post this as an answer and add some explanation?

Comment: If you run `ifconfig` on your host, you will usually see (at least) two interfaces, a localhost interface and an external interface; if you bind to 127.0.0.1 a process will be inaccessible from off-host.  A Docker container has a private network namespace and its own private localhost, so if you bind to that, in the same way, it will be unreachable from outside its container.